# lua https request with proxy return 501 error code

Tags: sockets, curl, proxy, lua

I use socket.http to get info from a https url with proxy:
here is my codes:

```
   local https = require("socket.http")
   local r, c, h, s = https.request{
   url = "https://www.google.fr",
   proxy="http://proxy:3128/"
   }

   print(r, c, h, s)
```

I have a error:" HTTP/1.1 501 Not Implemented
Unsupported Request Method and Protocol, Squid does not support all request methods for all access protocols."

But when I test url http with proxy:

```
   url = "http://www.google.fr",
   proxy="http://proxy:3128/"
```

or url https without proxy:

```
   url = "https://www.google.fr"
```

It is OK.

It seems just https with proxy does not work. May be the socket.http does not support https with proxy or my proxy squid does not support https from lua socket request?

But when I use curl in lua to require an url https with proxy: os.capture("curl -x http://proxy.com:3128" -XGET https://www.google.fr), it is OK .

So somebody can help me? Thank you !!!

Comment: I have used ssl.https, but it don't support proxy, I 've a error "not support proxy" here is my code: local https = require("ssl.https") local r, c, h, s = https.request{ url = "https://google.fr";, proxy="proxy:3128/"; }

Answer (score 0):

`socket.http` doesn't support https. You need to be using [luasec](https://github.com/brunoos/luasec) and its `ssl.https` module instead.

Comment: I have used ssl.https, but it don't support proxy, I 've a error "not support proxy" here is my code:   local https = require("ssl.https")
   local r, c, h, s = https.request{
   url = "https://www.google.fr",
   proxy="http://proxy:3128/"
   }

Comment: I think it's by design. How do you plan to use the proxy with https? If you terminate the SSL connection on the proxy, then you need to provide a certificate and it become MITM, but if you don't terminate the connection, then you can't see traffic, so the proxy is not useful. If you do the former, then you don't need luasec: just open http connection, but make the proxy to open https connection to the target.